# C++11/ Auto assign me a bool?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
TGuildMemberContainer::iterator it;
if ((it = m_member.find (p->dwPID)) == m_member.end())
{
    m_member.insert (std::make_pair (p->dwPID, TGuildMember (p->dwPID, p->bGrade, p->isGeneral, p->bJob, p->bLevel, p->dwOffer, p->szName)));
}
else
{
    TGuildMember& r_gm = it->second;
    r_gm.pid = p->dwPID;
    r_gm.grade = p->bGrade;
    r_gm.job = p->bJob;
    r_gm.offer_exp = p->dwOffer;
    r_gm.is_general = p->isGeneral;
}
```

Hi, i want to apply auto transform intro my codes, but i'm stuck.
If i add auto

```
if (auto it = m_member.find (p->dwPID) == m_member.end())
```

The auto assign a `bool`

```
if ( bool it = m_member.find (p->dwPID) == m_member.end())
```

This say Visual Studio intelisense.

My question, why auto assign me a bool and not the corect iteration range ?

Comment: Here, take these: `()` ;-)

Comment: It can't be done the way you seem to want to, because of the [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). You have to declare the variable (using `auto`) outside the condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the compiler is parsing it as:

```
    if (auto it = (m_member.find (p->dwPID) == m_member.end()))
```

which is a boolean expression.  You can't write it as:

```
    if ((auto it = m_member.find (p->dwPID)) == m_member.end())
```

because putting the variable declaration inside brackets like that is not allowed.

I find creating variables in `if` hard to read.  Just use:

```
    const auto it = m_member.find(p->dwPID);
    if (it == m_member.end())
    ...
```

Comment: As side commentary, I like defining variables in conditional logic because it forces scope.  In your example you've got a dangling iterator `it` hanging around in your scope.  Doing superfluous brackets {} just to force scope in this instance is messy in my opinion.  I'd rather see support for declaring in conditionals expanded...

Comment: Fair enough.  I try and keep the size of enclosing scope down so that it's not too much of a problem.  I'd only countenance the {} if the variable was something whose destructor was important (like a lock guard).  I find it hard to read because I don't like casting a non-bool variable to bool.  I tend to prefer `if (ptr != nullptr)` over `if (ptr)`.

Comment: why you guys always use const? I mean, should i use const intro evry auto transform ?

Comment: I always use const (unless I can't) because it makes it easier for me to reason about the program, and it makes it easier for the compiler to reason about it (and the more the compiler can reason about the program, the better it can optimize).

Answer (score 0):

In C++17, this can be done as

```
if (auto it = m_member.find (p->dwPID); it == m_member.end())
```

which avoids the scope problem mentioned in the other answer.